# More efficient way of transferring int from .txt to array

Tags: java, arrays, int

So I'm currently making a 2D game in which the map is pre-generated in a .txt file and then read and loaded into an array.

The array is stored in the World class (I'm using greenfoot), and the method in which I am doing this is: (map is declared and initialized to the size of the world from before, and the map is a perfect rectangle)

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner ( new File("map.txt"));
for(int i = 0; i<map.length;i++)
{
   for( int j = 0;j<map[0].length; j++;)
   {
    map[i][j]=scan.NextInt();
   }
}
```

(exceptions are caught and scanner is closed after)
My map is currently 600x5000, and this method of transferring the data seems to be really slow. Is there any way I could speed it up or use an more efficient way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try to make every 2 bytes (=every 2 characters) representing a block of map. So you could save some running time in retrieving the map

Comment: In the competition-coding world, it is recommended to use a [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) instead of a `Scanner` for reading data since it is faster.  This may be advantageous in your situation as well.

Comment: Or even every byte is a block if you are not in need of more than 256 objects in your game

Comment: @AdamCherti hi, i'll look into that. currently 1 int represents 1 block. I have a map 5000x600 of blocks LOL. so i'll definitely have more than 256 objects.

Comment: I was meaning by objects the objects of your game (wall, sand, etc.). And If you have less than 256 objects (whom can be represented by one byte only) you could make each byte (=each character) of your file being a block of map instead of writing an int in many characters.

Comment: @AdamCherti yup that's what im doing (at least attempting). I have 0-7 right now. I also tried out bufferedreader and it's giving me weird numbers like 59 and stuff like that. Do i just use the ascii conversion chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing the data in text format, try using a binary format meant to handle binary data.

If you do not want to add any libraries, try java serialization/deserialization, using this you will be able to store the complete array and read it as a complete array.

Comment: hey, I haven't learned this yet in grade 12 computer science. =p any simpler way?

Comment: It's not difficult. A file is a list of bytes representing characters. So the e letter is in reality a number e.g 152. So every byte of your file would be a number less than 256 because a byte can represent numbers from 0 to 255. And this number would represent the "code" of a map block.

Comment: It will be much faster. Otherwise, if you choose to scan ints then it's your choice and you will have to wait for the map loading and do as every other game : display a "leading" screen